# How to properly get_object in s3 and check_sum

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to validate integrity of my data by downloading an object and hashing it and passing the md5 along with the upload to another bucket but I get this error

```
The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received
```

Here is my code

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3.get_object(Bucket='ed-test', Key='test')


md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
md5_hash.update(response['Body'].read())
contents_md5 = md5_hash.hexdigest()
contents_md5_ = base64.b64encode(bytes.fromhex(contents_md5)).decode('utf-8')


metadata = {
    "md5sum": contents_md5_
}

s3.put_object(Body=response['Body'].read(), Bucket='ed-test-2', Key='test1', Metadata=metadata, ContentMD5=contents_md5_)
```

Comment: The second time you call `Body=response['Body'].read()` it will return an empty bytes string.

Comment: You'll need to assign the body to a variable (eg `body=response['Body'].read()` and then use the `body` variable in both places.